# "gulp serve" will return this error "ReferenceError: primordials is not defined"

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, spfx-webparts, gulp

I have 2 versions of node.js, as follow:-

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 17.1.0 (x64) and npm.
C:\Windows\System32>nvm list

    16.13.0
    8.16.2
```

Now i am trying to run `gulp serve` on this SPFx web part @ https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-enhanced-list-formatting .. but i got this error:-

```
C:\spfx-MyModalPopup>gulp serve
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:47:5
    at req_ (C:\spfx-MyModalPopup\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (C:\spfx-MyModalPopup\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\spfx-MyModalPopup\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)

C:\spfx-MyModalPopup>nvm use 16.13.0
exit status 145: The directory is not empty.
```

so what is going on ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running `gulp serve` command, first make sure you successfully select a node version. When you run `nvm list`, make sure you have `(Currently using 64-bit executable)` next to the correct node version. If you don't see it, then your `nvm use` didn't work.

```
    14.15.0
    12.13.0
    10.24.0
    10.23.0
  * 8.16.2  (Currently using 64-bit executable)
    6.10.3
```

Overall, it seems you didn't install nvm for windows correctly. Please, make sure you read the [nvm for Windows' manual](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) and follow it exactly. Don't cut corners and don't jump to the next steps until you do it.

**Notable quotes**

> Uninstall any existing versions of Node.js before installing NVM for
> Windows (otherwise you'll have conflicting versions). Delete any
> existing Node.js installation directories (e.g.,
> %ProgramFiles%\nodejs) that might remain. NVM's generated symlink will
> not overwrite an existing (even empty) installation directory.

> nvm-windows runs in an Admin shell. You'll need to start powershell or
> Command Prompt as Administrator to use nvm-windows

Overall, this is not a SharePoint-related question. You will get better chances of getting help on the Stack Overflow. I see you [cross-posted the same question there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69949394/gulp-serve-will-return-this-error-referenceerror-primordials-is-not-defined).